# JS sort method clones the strings in the array but the array length is the same

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, duplicates

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqo2dzws/)

fiddle has more items so it is with the issue. please check it

I tried using a smaller sized array and it works until some number of elements but after some point, it duplicates strings though sorting works. Probably overwrites one string on another. Thanks very much

```js
let uninames = `adnan menderes university
  ahi evran university
  akdeniz university
  afyon kocatepe university
  anadolu university
  ankara university
  istanbul arel university
  atatürk university
  atilim university
  bahcesehir university
  balikesir university
  baskent university
  celal bayar university
  beykent university
  bilecik university
  istanbul bilgi university
  bilkent university
  boğaziçi university
  cag university
  cankaya university
  canakkale (18th march) university
  cukurova university
  cumhuriyet (republik) university
  dokuz eylül university
  batman university
  bayburt university`;

let unarr = uninames.split("\n");

unarr.sort((a, b) => a > b);
for (let i = 0; i < unarr.length; i++)
  document.write(i + ") " + unarr[i] + "<br>");
```

Comment: I don't see any duplicate value..

Comment: you need a proper sorting function. please visit the above link.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can you please check the jsfiddle link I provided or from here https://jsfiddle.net/aqo2dzws/